# Javascript: Calculating average velocity or speed

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am learning basic physics and I am trying to apply this concept into programming: https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/one-dimensional-motion/displacement-velocity-time/v/calculating-average-velocity-or-speed

You can see the formula at exactly 6:00.

I want the ball to move to exactly 300px at an average velocity. So Im trying to somehow apply the information in the video practically. So while im learning all the basics of physics Im also applying it in programming. This is my first attempt:

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1phfkb7s/3/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var direction = 200;
var displacement = 5;
var time = 10;


function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(displacement - direction / time, 75, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.stroke();

    displacement += 1;
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

This is the formula:

https://www.google.ch/search?q=velocity+formula&espv=2&rlz=1C1TEUA_enCH660CH660&biw=1366&bih=667&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjt2JXXkaLJAhVIWBQKHdXJCckQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=GsRnur1vRdqEyM%3A

Comment: Did you have a question? Is there a result you're expecting to see? What's happening instead?

Comment: @PaulRoub sorry, I will add more information in my question

Comment: @PaulRoub you may want to have a look again.

Comment: `I want the ball to move to exactly 300px at an average velocity` what does that mean? Go 300px in what time, 10 secs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`displacement += 1;` is wrong because it simply moves the ball one pixel each iteration. Since you're using `requestAnimationFrame`, you need to add a sense of time in order to calculate where the ball should be at any point.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var distance = 300;    // you said 300 pixels, not 200
var position = 5;      // renamed those as well for clarity
var totalTime = 10;    //
var startTime = new Date();  // the time at which the code starts

var out = document.getElementById('o');

function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(position, 75, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2);  // we only need the position
    ctx.stroke();

    // here we calculate the next step based on:     
    var expired = (new Date() - startTime) / 1000;  // the expired time in seconds
    position = expired * distance / totalTime;      // multiplied by the "step per second"
  
    out.innerHTML = "Seconds: " + Math.floor(expired) + "<br>Position: " + Math.floor(position);
  
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' height='120' width='600'></canvas>
<p id="o"></p>
```

---

`displacement += 1` would only make sense if you update your canvas once a second by using `setInterval` or something:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var distance = 300;    // you said 300 pixels, not 200
var position = 0;      // renamed those as well for clarity
var totalTime = 10;    //

var out = document.getElementById('o');

function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(position * (distance / totalTime), 75, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2);  // we only need the position
    ctx.stroke();

    position++;
}

setInterval(render, 1000);
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' height='120' width='600'></canvas>
<p id="o"></p>
```

Comment: It works but what I dont understand is you did: expired * distance / totalTime which is different to the: 15km North / time  example in the video

Comment: So that means I cant use the formulas exactly as they are but need to change them in order to make them work in programming?

Comment: Didn't watch the video, but if you're referring to `delta distance / delta time`, think of it as (commutation applied) `distance / expired * totalTime`, which is the same thing (distance / delta time, basically)